# Is it possible to surpress that "input" jumps to the next line?

Tags: matlab, input

I got a code similar to this:

```
fprintf('Give a vector: \n')
fprintf('1. Vector/Matrix: X = {')
FirstVector = input('','s');
fprintf('}')
fprintf('\n')
```

It should print out something like this:

```
Give a vector: 
1. Vector/Matrix: X = {UserInput}
```

Instead I get this:

```
Give a vector: 
1. Vector/Matrix: X = {UserInput

}
```

The `input`-function is making a `\n`. How can I avoid that? The documentation of `input` is of no use, it doesn't even tell that `input` behaves that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around this inherent limitation of [`input`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) by adding a [backspace character](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/backspace-ascii-code-8.html) to the `fprintf` after the input. You can also condense your code into two lines, like so:

```
FirstVector = input('Give a vector: \n1. Vector/Matrix: X = {', 's');
fprintf([char(8) '}\n']);
```

Entering a `1`:

```
Give a vector: 
1. Vector/Matrix: X = {1}
```

Note also that the `'s'` option is for capturing character/string input. If you want the user to enter numeric values, leave that out.

Comment: I like the condensation. Golfing isn't always necessary, but calling the same function four times is neither.